# Python Function with 2 values

Tags: python-3.x

Homework Question I am struggling with

Specification:

The third function you will write should be called ‘excelPrep’. Your function should take one (1) argument:
a string that will contain the Excel formula. The function should return two (2) values: first, a string
containing the modified Excel formula; and second an integer containing the number of dollar signs
removed.

Example Test Case:

```
excelPrep(‘=SUM($A$4:$A$12)’)
```

returns

```
=sum(a4:a12)
```

and

```
4
```

Comment: Why smart quotes?

Comment: And what specifically are you struggling with? [Asking for others to write the whole code for you is not nice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303701/when-a-users-question-amounts-to-write-this-code-for-me-what-is-the-best-cou).

Answer (score 0):

I will not write the entire code since this is stackoverflow and not homework helper so I think you should complete with your own mind.

The function should be something like:

1. Remove the `$` by checking every letter in the string with for loop, at the same time add a number counter so that you can know how many `$`s you’ve removed. Making the input from `=SUM($A$4:$A$12)` into `=SUM(A4:A12)`.
2. You could return the value now however if the assignment specified to make the letters in to lowercase. Make a new string variable and append all the letters from the function returned variable `=SUM(A4:A12)` check if the letter is a number if not `.lower()`. Which leaves you with `=sum(a4:a12)`.
3. To return two values, in the end of your function type `return stringVariable, integerVariable`. Just be careful when ever you are calling the function, you will need to variables to store the outputs. Like: `a, b = excelPrep(“=SUM($A$4:$A$12)` which for your information `a = “=sum(a4:a12)”`, `b = 4`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But... why are you using smart quotes? `“”` and not `""`?

Comment: @user202729 Because I am typing on an iPhone.